# Bulk update Exchange Manager/Direct Reports data

Tags: exchange, user-management

I'm looking for an easy way to quickly update (and keep up to date) the Manager - Direct Reports data in Exchange Online. Right now, the only way I have is to go into EAC and manually update one user at a time. I'd also like to find the best way to keep the relationship up to date once we get everyone updated.

**Clarification** As far as "keeping the relationship up to date," I was thinking of either pulling the information from some other source on a schedule or giving a non-technical HR employee a way to make the change directly.

Comment: The information is in AD. Does your Office 365 sync with onsite AD or is it self-contained?

Comment: Self contained. There is some talk about implementing DirSync, but I don't know if that will actually happen. I think that would just make the question go from keeping Exchange up to date to keeping AD up to date....

Comment: At the time of the question, I was under the impression Powershell wasn't available, thus the complaint about EAC. Since then, I've cleared up that misconception... Dare I downvote my own question? Or is that a question for Meta? ;)

Comment: Still a useful question, IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell. Use Powershell. If you have the data in an external file already, you can put in a CSV, import that, and loop through it line-by-line to update in bulk.

Comment: That's what I expect I'll end up having to do, but I was hoping for something a little more automatic. (More accurately, something a little more "here you go, HR, here's how you handle this.")

Comment: OK, that's not what you asked at all. Your question, as asked, was for executing bulk updates, not delegating such tasks to non-technical users who won't have full admin access to AD.

Comment: This answer still applies. HR data is probably in a database somewhere. Write a PowerShell script that pulls the data from the database and updates AD.

Comment: Fair point. At the time of the question, I was under the false impression we couldn't use Powershell. Since then, I figured out for myself (well, Googled) how to create a remote session and got that working, so this is probably the best answer I could hope for to my badly conceived question.